# Closing a popup window with powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

At the moment I am working on a script to automate a process in IE to add Computer Names and their MACs so we can image them. The page has two fields one for MAC and one for a computer name then a add new button. At the moment it is still manual entry, but I intend for it to read from a csv to do large groups at a time.

The problem I am currently having is whenever there is a duplicate record it tells you with a javascript popup. The popup disables interaction with the IE page. I need a way to close the popups in between entries.

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
cls

$URL = ""
$iterator = 1;

#starts IE
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"

#visible for testing purposes
$ie.visible = $true
#$ie.silent = $true
$ie.navigate($URL)

#Manual Input
$newMAC = read-host -prompt 'Input MAC here'
$newNAME = read-host -prompt 'Input Computer Name here'

while($ie.Busy -eq $true) { start-sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

#enters information into appropriate fields and clicks the add button
($ie.document.getElementsByName("mc_id") |select -first 1).value = $newNAME;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("mac_id") |select -first 1).value = $newMAC;
($ie.document.getElementsByName("btnAddNew") |select -first 1).click();
```

Edit:

I have decided for the moment with a sloppy solution in closing my com object for each new entry. I am however now having issues with importing a csv for the script to read.

Comment: Yikes, I didn't even know powershell could do that. As this is tagged with JavaScript, would a JavaScript solution be acceptable?

Comment: One possible way would be to use one of the functions on user32.dll like [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx)The p/invoke signature could be [found here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.DestroyWindow) A here's a [guide for using P/invoke signatures](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2009/01/19/powershell-pinvoke-walkthrough/)

Comment: @BenH I'm going to look into this, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you scrape all the existing MACs out of the page/site, and then do the check in your code, and avoid putting duplicates in at all? Can you POST directly to the back end with `Invoke-WebRequest` and avoid IE and avoid running the JavaScript at all?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Unfortunately not, my team only has access to the front end of this page and only to add new names. The worst part is the popup isn't even necessary it just informs you that there was a duplicate and its overwriting it.

Comment: @P.McDevitt you should still be able to capture what the browser submits when you add a new name using the developer tools or a local MITM proxy (e.g. Fiddler 4), and then replicate that from a script. It sounds likely that it would be a HTTP POST with some standard form submit content. The popup only comes from IE running JavaScript that says "show a popup", and if you skip past it and just do an authentication and form submit from another client, you wouldn't have to deal with the popup.

Answer (score 3):

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
if($wshell.AppActivate('Message from webpage'))
{
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('{Enter}')
}
```

This code will set the active window to the window that has the title of      `"Message from webpage"` So adjust it to match the pop up title.

Then it will send the `Enter` key press. You might be able to adjust this to send a combination of keys to dismiss the pop up. Perhaps even send `ALT+F4` using `::SendWait('%{f4}')`

I am assuming the Javascript pop-up opens in a new window. Alternatively I would see what other JavaScript is used on the page and if its only for the pop-up look in to disabling Javascript on that page for the com object.

**EDIT:**

To disable the Javascript you would need to turn off all java code execution for this page by adding it to the restricted sites security zone and making sure the javascript execution for the zone is turned off. But I have a better idea, you could use the com object to try and break the pages pop up function:

```
$ie = new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("http://www.echoecho.com/jswindows03.htm")
$ie.Document.body.innerHTML = $ie.Document.body.innerHTML -replace "popup\('www.yahoo.com', 'Win1', 300, 300\);", ""
```

This code block opens a page that has a demo javascript pop up function, It then removes the function call from the buttons `onclick` event. Causing the pop to never be called. You can do the same trick I have done to modify the client copy of the page and break the javascript or modify it to never display.

Comment: I just tried this and it does not seem to switch to the pop up, but it does send the enter. How would I go about disabling the javascript in a com object?

Comment: Added a update to my answer. Without seeing the page source code I cant solve all your problems but that should be enough to get you going. Programatically editing the pages html code to remove the alert javascript seems to work. `-replace` will regex match the html and replace it with `""` nothing in my example

Comment: @P.McDevitt Any luck?